# How to whitelist digitalocean load balancer in kubernetes network policy?

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I've configured next network policy in my namespace:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: np-testing-allow
  namespace: testing
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          purpose: monitoring
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          purpose: ci
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          environmentName: testing
```

But after that managed load balancer for nginx-ingress is down. How I can whitelist managed load balancer in network policy?

I've already tried to whitelist VPC CIDR and load balancer public IP and it didn't help

*What I want to achieve*: to "testing" namespace must be allowed "ci" and "monitoring" namespaces, but in the same time I want to allow traffic from Digitalocean load balancer.

*From which Namespace you want to send traffic?* my question is related only to ingress traffic, we want to allow incoming traffic from digitalocean load balancer

*Where is your nginx-ingress located?* in the "testing" namespace

*Do you want to have traffic from your nginx-ingress pod to pods on another Namespace?* no, we need traffic only inside "testing" namespace

*What and where should be whitelisted exactly* DigitalOcean load balancer should be whitelisted in "testing" namespace network policy

Comment: We need to know more details here in order to help you. What exactly do you want to achieve? From which Namespace you want to send traffic? Where is your nginx-ingress located? Do you want to have traffic from your nginx-ingress pod to pods on another Namespace? What and where should be whitelisted exactly. Please, edit your question with the necessary details.

Comment: Also, do you have your cluster on-prem or do you use Digitalocean managed kubernetes?

Comment: I've added details, hope this is enough

Comment: Have you maybe tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327554/kubernetes-networkpolicy-allow-loadbalancer)? Also, what is the incoming IP that you see in nginx-ingrss controller when you are doing requests? I mean it is your public IP or the loadbalancer IP?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I do not have access to DigitalOcean. I have analyzed and tested this using my k8s 1.18.2 cluster on GCP. Make sure that you can meet the [prerequisites](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#prerequisites) on DigitalOcean as well:

> Network policies are implemented by the network plugin. To use network
> policies, you must be using a networking solution which supports
> NetworkPolicy. Creating a NetworkPolicy resource without a controller
> that implements it will have no effect

There are some resources that can help you achieve your goal. First, check out this guide: [ALLOW traffic from external clients](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/a18f9e6e/08-allow-external-traffic.md#allow-traffic-from-external-clients):

> This Network Policy enables external clients from the public Internet
> directly or via a Load Balancer to access to the pod.

In order to work, both `Service type=LoadBalancer` and `Ingress` resources must allow ALL traffic to the pods selected by these resources.

See the [example](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/a18f9e6e/08-allow-external-traffic.md#example) below:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: web-allow-external
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  ingress:
  - from: []
```

> The following manifest allows traffic from all sources (both internal
> from the cluster and external).

I have reproduced your use case with the following steps:

1. Installed Nginx Ingress and labeled it with `purpose=testing`.
2. Created and labeled the following namespaces: `ingress-nginx` as `purpose=testing`, `monitoring` as `purpose=monitoring` and `ci` as `purpose=ci`.
3. Applied a `deployment` and a `service` in `default`, `ingress-nginx`, `monitoring` and `ci` namespaces:

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my1
  namespace: <one_of_the_listed_above>
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my1
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my1
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my1
  namespace: <one_of_the_listed_above>
  labels:
    run: my1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: my1
```

4. Created an Ingress:

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my1
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    # If the class annotation is not specified it defaults to "gce".
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my1
          servicePort: 80
```

5. Verified the connectivity between namespaces and load balancer.
6. Created the following `NetworkPolicy`:

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-monitoring-ci
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          purpose: ci
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          purpose: monitoring
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          purpose: testing
```

With the configs above the pods in `ingress-nginx` namespaces should be able to receive traffic from `monitoring` and `ci` namespaces. Also, they will internally receive traffic inside `ingress-nginx` namespace which is labeled as `testing`.

Also check if your [externalTrafficPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip) in load balancer service is set to `Local` or `Cluster`. If it is set to `Cluster` the Ingress will have IP of the Node where Ingress pod is running. If that happens you also need to create the following config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  podSelector:
     matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
  ingress:
  - from:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except: 
        - 10.16.0.0/14 #pod ip range
```

Using `cidr: 0.0.0.0/0` will allow all the incoming traffic and adding the `except:` will let you adjust your needs depending on the DigitalOcean configuration (which I don't have access to).

Also notice that from k8s v1.19 the `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` for Ingress is replaced with `v1`. Make sure you are using the right versioning.

Last thing to remember is that you should also use those policies for egress and not only for ingress. While blocking the egress you might encounter a problem with DNS resolve which will require you to add rules in order for pods to be able to send requests to DNS. More details [here](https://blog.vamp.io/network-policies-made-easy-on-gke/).